# Selenium python при обходе цикла проскакивает страницы

Tags: python, selenium, beautiful-soup

Я только начинаю программировать, поэтому прошу прощения за корявость кода
Мне необходимо найти на сайте файлы и загрузить их в папку. Запрос на нужный файл генерируется из обхода цикла, но при запуске кода все время пара файлов просто игнорируются... Если наблюдать за процессом парсинга в открытом браузере, то скачаются все файлы, если оставить в фоне, то не все В чем может быть проблема?

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import shutil
import os
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.atsenergo.ru/")
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Участникам розничного рынка')[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Ставки тарифа на услуги по передаче электроэнергии, используемые для целей определения расходов на оплату нормативных потерь')[0].click()
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Европа')]")[0].click()

months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
years = ['2019', '2018']

for year in years:
    for month in months:
        filename = year + month + '01' + '_FRSTF_ATS_REPORT_PUBLIC_FSK.xls'
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        try:
            driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format('01.'+ month + '.' + year))[0].click()
            pSource= driver.page_source 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(pSource, "html.parser")
            l = soup.find_all('a')
            for link in l:
                if filename in link:
                    link1 = 'https://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport' + link.get('href') # определяем ссылку на файл для скачивания
                    r = requests.get(link1)  # запрашиваем файл для скачивания
                    output = open(filename, 'wb')
                    output.write(r.content)
                    output.close()
                    source_files = os.getcwd()
                    shutil.move(source_files + '\\' + filename, 'D:\\Сети\\2019\\ФСК' + '\\' + filename)
                    print('файл', filename, 'скачен и сохранен в папке', 'D:\\Сети\\2019\\ФСК')
                    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Календарь')]")[0].click()
        except IndexError:
            print('за', month, 'месяц', year, 'год данные не найдены')
            continue
```

Comment: В итоге точно присутствуют на сайте, но не скачались при обходе файлы за 20190301, 20180401, 20180901, 20181101

Comment: А что если файлы скачивать не реквестом, а самим браузером. Можно в настройках браузера отключить подтверждение загрузкам, и файлы будут скачиваться при нажатии на ссылку сразу и в папку по умолчанию (папку можно настроить также в опциях самого браузера). Так вы избавитесь и от реквеста и от Супа, и будете работать только Селениум-Браузер)))) Если вам такой вариант подойдёт, я напишу ответ)

Comment: В настройках стоит загрузка в папку по умолчанию, но при клике через selenium все равно запрашивается папка на сохранение

Comment: "Можно в настройках браузера отключить подтверждение загрузкам"? я про это и говорил)))) Подтверждение загрузки, это настраиваемое поведение) диалоговое окно можно отключить или для отдельного типа файлов, или просто для всех загрузок)

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, Exception происходит не из-за того, что скрипт не находит элемент на странице, а из-за то-го, что он пытается кликнуть найденный элемент слишком рано, когда элемент ещё не готов.

Советую отказаться от `implicitly_wait` и использовать explicit waits подход ([документация](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (
        By.XPATH, 
        "//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format('01.'+ month + '.' + year)
    )
).click()
```

Comment: В это случае выходит TimeoutException

Comment: @Gaillardinija Пока что не смогу более помочь - в отъезде до четверга, без компьютера. Приеду - гляну ещё. Попробуйте заменить условие на ec.presence_of_element_located, чтобы увидеть, есть ли эти элементы на странице